# pointer array changes values, When assigning memery using malloc to other pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

An array of `uint64*` (pointer array) prints correct value. When re-print these value in another loop(same copy), the values have changed automatically. In-between there is usage of `malloc()` function. If i comment out `malloc` lines `g_m` and `gm_rm` then program works fine.

```
for(i=0;i<num_of_msg_blocks;i++) // loop 1
 printf("%lu -%08x ",i,msg_block[i]);    

g_m= malloc(num_of_msg_blocks+1);
gm_rn= malloc(num_of_msg_blocks+1);

for(i=0;i<num_of_msg_blocks;i++)  //loop 2
 printf("%lu -%08x ",i,msg_block[i]);
```

**Loop 1 output:**

```
0- 00313233 
1- 000a3132 
2- 00330a31 
3- 0032330a 
4- 0061736a 
5- 006b6264 
6- 006b6a61 
7- 0062730a 
8- 00383231 
9- 00343837 
10- 00323334 
11- 00366862 
12- 00776a6b 
13- 000a7364
```

**Loop 2 output:**

```
0- 00313233 
1- 000a3132 
2- 00330a31 
3- 0032330a 
4- 0061736a 
5- 006b6264 
6- 006b6a61 
7- 0062730a 
8- 00383231 
9- 00343837 
10- 00000031 
11- 00000000 
12- 00776a6b 
13- 000a7364
```

From 0-9 both loop output same values, but 10 and onward the values incorrectly changes.

The above variable declaration is as:

```
uint32_t *msg_block;
msg_block = malloc(num_of_msg_blocks+1);   
uint64_t *g_m;  
uint64_t *gm_rn;
```

Why printed values depends on malloc, (they are independent) ? How to correct this?

Comment: Please provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 3):

You're not allocating enough space for `msg_block`. You're allocating `num_of_msg_blocks+1` bytes, but you need to multiply that by the size of each element.

```
msg_block = malloc((num_of_msg_blocks+1) * sizeof *msg_block);
```